# Disable change backgound function

Tags: desktop-background, functions

How to disable "change background" function from the Terminal on Ubuntu 18.04? And set one standard background for all the time? Thanks :)

Comment: It is possible in other way.. but do you really want it to control via Terminal only?

Comment: Actually not. I just want it to be invisible to the other students. It would be such a pleasure if you share with me the other way I can do it :)

Comment: Okay then, I'm waiting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit on Apr 11th 2020***

You may be interested in this script https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/backgrounds_lock

---

If you want to lock the background picture

Warning: No Warranty on below Script Files.. Understand it first.. then Proceed on your Own..

Create a Script named `lbg.sh` short for "Lock Back Ground" with below content

```
#!/bin/bash

keys=/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-bg
locks=/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/background

touch /etc/dconf/profile/user
echo "user-db:user" >> /etc/dconf/profile/user
echo "system-db:local" >> /etc/dconf/profile/user
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/local.d
touch $keys
echo "[org/gnome/desktop/background]" >> $keys
echo "picture-uri='file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Halifax_Sunset_by_Vlad_Drobinin.jpg'" >> $keys
echo "picture-options='zoom'" >> $keys
echo "primary-color='#456789'" >> $keys
echo "secondary-color='#FFFFFF'" >> $keys
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks
touch $locks
echo "/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri" >> $locks
echo "/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options" >> $locks
echo "/org/gnome/desktop/background/primary-color" >> $locks
echo "/org/gnome/desktop/background/secondary-color" >> $locks
dconf update
```

Other Script named `rbg.sh` short for "Release Back Ground" with below content

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -r /etc/dconf/profile/user /etc/dconf/db/local.d
dconf update
```

to lock the desktop background run the script with `sudo`.
if you have saved the `lbg.sh` script in your home folder, then run

```
sudo /bin/bash /home/<user>/lbg.sh
```

This will lock the picture-uri value given in above script

Then logout and logback in

To make the things to normal run the second script `rbg.sh` for example

```
sudo /bin/bash /home/<user>/rbg.sh
```

Then logout and logback in

[image]

[image]

---

Source: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-background.html.en

Comment: It sounds silly... but I tried every way I can find to set up this but I can't.. Can u help me, after long time..? 

Comment: Man.. you're awesome! Thanks a lot. It works perfectly like a chapm

Comment: Hi, Did you run script or just renamed .desktop file?

Comment: I run the script. I created a text file with the above contend, saved it as lbg.sh and I run it into the terminal with sudo. As in the animation, I can go to the right-click change background function, but when I change it nothing happens