# Password protect the process of changing wallpaper

Tags: password, desktop-background

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/533790/1066037), but that solution didn't worked for me.

I have some quite weird requirements, I need to prevent the process of changing wallpaper in Ubuntu. What I would **not** want to do is have some python script run as daemon process which periodically changes wallpaper.

I want to make sure that nobody can change wallpaper without writing that particular password. According to the linked post, you need to change a file located at `/usr/bin` having the name `gsettings`. I followed the same process as described, and successfully changed the content of that file, but nothing seems to happen.

How can I password protect changing the wallpaper?

I am using Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Wallpaper is different for each user account. Are you saying that multiple people are using the same non-guest account? If so, you have bigger problems than wallpaper....

Comment: @user535733 Sorry, I forgot to mention that only one user uses this machine and there are no other guest accounts.

Comment: @EReload... is ur requirment to lock the thing with password only?? background can be locked with other way around. since ur Question is particularly about "password".. I am afraid to share you the link..

Comment: @PRATAP No, my only incentive is to prevent changing wallpaper.

Comment: 0k then here is the link.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1179663/739431

Comment: @PRATAP That works! Thank you for that solution. Do you know how to apply the same for lock screen wallpaper?

Comment: yes.. You can achieve that by editing the same script.. `lbg.sh` But I need to do it and then only tell you the changes required.. may be less than 59minutes..

Comment: do you want separate script or editing the same script for both?

Comment: Any would work...

Comment: Ok, I will edit the existing script and share you the file.. started working on it..

Comment: Hi can you go through this.. mean while I will upload the script file.. https://imgur.com/FZay35z

Comment: Hi.. Here is the file.. Change the paths of both the backgrounds and run the script  `lock.sh`.. It will overtake previous one `lbg.sh` https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/backgrounds_lock